# React - Handle Multiple SelectField

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the value of each selectField in a dynamic way inside a table.the problem is when i am changing one selectField it is not updating my selectfield setState and not updating selectfield value in selectfield.I can not figure out how i can change the selected field value in my dropdown

```html
class Forms extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      month: [],

    };
 
   
  }
handleMonth(index, value){
    let tmp = [...this.state.month];
    tmp[index] = value;
    this.setState({ month: tmp});
}
 
  render() {
 
    return (
 
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell style={{ color: "rgb(131, 132, 133)" }}>
                 Profiles:
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ color: "rgb(131, 132, 133)" }}>
                   Value
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {Profiles.map((row,index) => {
                  return (
                    <TableRow key={row.id}>
                      <TableCell
                        component="th"
                        style={{ color: "rgb(131, 132, 133)" }}
                        scope="row"
                      >
                        {row.id}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>
                        <Select
                          value={this.state.month[index] || null}
                          onChange={this.handleMonth.bind(this, index)}
                          style={{ position: "relative", width: "10vw" }}
                        >
                          {
                            this.props.data!==undefined ?
                            this.props.daployment.map(item => {
                              return <MenuItem value={item.name}>{item.name}</MenuItem>
                            }):""
                          }
                        </Select>
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
        
      
     
      
      
    
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is missing a few key details to make it a runnable application, so this is only speculation, but I think it's in how you're binding your onChange method. Here's a condensed example from one of my React apps.

Note that the onChange function will receive an event as the first param, and that I'm not binding it from inside my `render` method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      regions: [
        { name: 'Select Region', value: null },
        { name: 'East', value: 'east' },
        { name: 'West', value: 'west' },
        { name: 'Pacific', value: 'pacific' },
        { name: 'Atlantic', value: 'atlantic' }
      ],
      names: [
        { name: 'Select Name', value: null },
        { name: 'Peter', value: 'peter' },
        { name: 'Paul', value: 'paul' },
        { name: 'Mary', value: 'mary' }
      ],
      region: '',
      name: ''
    };
  }
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    const { regions, names, region, name } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <select
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={region}
          name="region"
        >
          {regions.map(item => (
            <option
              key={item.value}
              value={item.value}
            >
              {item.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <select
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={name}
          name="name"
        >
          {names.map(item => (
            <option
              key={item.value}
              value={item.value}
            >
              {item.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <p>Selected Region: {region}</p>
        <p>Selected Name: {name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

## Demo

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/WarmheartedImportantConstant)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am having more than one select field so when i m changing one selectfield value it is refllecting all selecfield.I want to Handle Multiple SelectField in table.Not one selectfield.

Comment: Could you possibly boil down your example into a repl.it so that it can be debugged easier? What library are you using for your `<Select>` component?

Comment: please find link library with example.https://codesandbox.io/s/o440zwm5y6. I want to update select-field  based on selected value. not all the selectfield.

Comment: In your linked example, you've given all the fields the same `name` attribute and reference the same value from the state. Your update method uses the `name` attribute as the key. You need to make these all unique, e.g. `value={this.state.age1}` and `name="age1"`, `value={this.state.age2}` and `name="age2"`

Comment: I want to use map and iterate selectfield through it.I found similar example.But it is not working properly.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356700/react-handle-multiple-selectfield-in-table

Comment: I updated my example with two select drop downs. Normally the data would come from an API or some other resource and not all be stored into `this.state`

Comment: I want to iterate selectfield and menuitem both and when it will select the value of dropdown and update selected dropdown.Please see the example.                                                                                {names.map(item => (
        <select
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={name}
          name="name"
        >
          {names.map(item => (
            <option
              key={item.value}
              value={item.value}
            >
              {item.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
     ))}

Comment: Your nested map doesn't really make sense. You're looping over the same data set to create `select` elements as you are for the `option` elements. Normally your `select` wouldn't be generated by a loop, unless you have all your fields specified in a well defined object.

Comment: can you please see this example.          
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356700/react-handle-multiple-selectfield-in-tableWhich is same thing i want.but when i try to use it my code then it is not working and not giving me the selected field answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got the answer.After passing handle to index handleMonth(event,index){
    const months = this.state.months;
    months[index]= event.target.value;
    console.log("chekcing values--->",months);
    this.setState({months});
      
}